# Check if controller is on top of the navigationController stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

How can I check inside a controller if it's on top of the navigationController stack? I.e. if the controller is the active view.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a property for that called `topViewController`. To check if your controller is topmost, do this:

```
BOOL topMost = ([self.navigationController.topViewController isEqual:self]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check its `topViewController` property.